# Получение интерфейса при помощи наследования

Tags: c++, наследование

Уважаемые участники, что вы можете сказать по поводу такого кода:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int x = 2020;

    class B& GetInterface()
    {
            // ...
            // Тут на самом деле делается нечто.
            // Но это не важно для вопроса
        return (B&)(*this);
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.GetInterface().f();
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли здесь неопределённое поведение? Является ли такой код допустимым, если в классе `B` нет переопределённых виртуальных функций класса `A`, данных - вообще ничего, кроме невиртуальных функций?

Comment: Именно этот код работает потому что здесь, по сути, нечему ломаться. А вот если добавить например в класс `B` свои данные, которые `f` также будет выводить или перенести `int x = 2020;` в класс `B`, вот тогда начнётся веселье.

Comment: @EOF уточнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть неопределенное поведение при разыменовании ссылки, полученной из `GetInterface`, так как ссылка на самом деле не ссылается на объект типа `B`. Такой код является недопустимым независимо от содержимого класса `B`.

> **7.2.1 Value category [basic.lval]**
> ...
> **11** If a program attempts to access (3.1) the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar (7.3.5) to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
> (11.1) the dynamic type of the object
> (11.2) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> (11.3) a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.